# How to make an image fill up depending on the value of an accompanying slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, canvas

I have a design requirement where I need to make a bottle which fills up with blue color, depending on the slider value. I'm pretty stumped on how to approach this. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: show us what you tried so far

Comment: @לבנימלכה Hey I haven't tried anything substantial yet as I am completely blank as to how to approach this particular problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could simply be done with some kind of percental range. You could use two images too. One for the empty bottle, one filled and overlay them. Should be pretty easy to do ...

One example below:

```js
let from = document.querySelector('#from'),
    to = document.querySelector('#to'),
    filling = document.querySelector('.filling');

[from, to].forEach(input =>
  input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    filling.style.top = from.value + '%';
    filling.style.height = (to.value - from.value) + '%';
  })
);
```

```css
.bottle {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 125px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fefefe;
}

.filling {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  top: 15%;
  height: 50%;
};
```

```html
from: <input id="from" value="15" />% - to: <input id="to" value="75" />%

<br /><br />

<div class="bottle">
  <div class="filling"></div>
</div>
```

Or, another way around, instead of calculate the filling, you could calculate the empty parts. This could make the following work easier. But this belongs to your task.

```js
let emptyTop = document.querySelector('.top'),
    emptyBottom = document.querySelector('.bottom');

document.querySelector('#from').addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  emptyTop.style.height = e.target.value + '%';
});

document.querySelector('#to').addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  emptyBottom.style.height = (100 - e.target.value) + '%';
});
```

```css
.bottle {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 125px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: blue;
}

.top, .bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

.top {
  top: 0;
  height: 15%;
}

.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 25%;
}
```

```html
from: <input id="from" value="15" />% - to: <input id="to" value="75" />%

<br /><br />

<div class="bottle">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you  @eisbehr for taking time out to answer this question in such thorough detail! You have been immensely helpful here and I can't thank you enough for such a well thought out answer!

Comment: Please note that with top-bottom (two part filling) there's a possibility of those parts of interleaving with each other, which @eisbehr didn't think about

Comment: Both examples has issues actually. These are only simple examples. There is more work to do to resolve this. This will just lead the way ...